# Unable to slice an array correctly

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am having the following array

```
import numpy as np
T = np.array(([1,-1,0,0,0,0],
              [3,0,5,0,0,0],
              [0,-1,0,9,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,-2,1],
              [3,1,0,0,2,0],
              [1,-2,1,0,2,2]))
```

I want to remove the first column and the last row of the array. So I should get:

```
T = [[-1 0 0 0 0],
    [0 5 0 0 0],
    [-1 0 9 0 0],
    [0 0 0 -2 1],
    [1 0 0 2 0]]
```

I wrote following line of code:

```
T = T[:len(T)-1][1:len(T[0])]
```

But I don't get the result I am expecting. The result I get is this:

```
[[ 3  0  5  0  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  0  9  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 -2  1]
 [ 3  1  0  0  2  0]]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and also the correct way to slice the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you slice an array like you did, what is returned is another array with the same number of dimensions. So your code is equivalent to:

```
T = T[:len(T)-1]
T = T[1:len(T[0])]
```

instead do:

```
T[:len(T)-1, 1:len(T[0])]
```

or just

```
T = T[:-1, 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just removing the first list not the first element in all lists you can try some thing like this

```
T = [i[1:] for i in T]
```

by using this line you loop in all the nested lists and delete the first element from it

you can read more about [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)